# Name clash between Less mixin and CSS selector

Tags: css, less, less-mixins

I have this simplified Less script

```css
.placeholder(@color: #333333) {
    &::-webkit-input-placeholder  { color: @color; }
}

input {
    .placeholder();
}

.placeholder {
    margin-top: 20px;
}
```

The output when I run this through my local compiler or [winless online less compiler](http://winless.org/online-less-compiler) is

```
input {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #333333;
}
.placeholder {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

Insted of the desired output

```css
input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #333333;
}
.placeholder {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

Is this a bug or am I missing something here?

By the result it looks to me like I can't have CSS-selectors with the same name as mixins with default values.

I'm running into this problem when compiling Bootstrap with my site specific code. In this particular case I can work around it, but as the project grows and I include other projects I can't imaging I have to keep track of any mixins with default values?

**Edit:** I see now that I should have read the manual and pretty much seen on the [first page of the docs](http://lesscss.org/features/) that everything can be treated as a mixin.

Comment: I don't think there is any straight forward solution to this one as this is the way Less works. However can your `.placeholder` selector be made more specific (like `div.placeholder` or similar)? That should solve the issue. I am not adding it as answer because this still is a workaround but will do so if you wish me to.

Comment: Thank you Harry. You may do so and I can tick it as accepted. Like you says it's how Less works and I would have known if I had RTFM.

Comment: I have just moved the Edit part to the bottom to make the question get prominence. Also just for your info, mentioning *Edit* etc are generally not required because SO does keep track of changes. It is not that it is bad but just that it is not required :)

Comment: I put a workaround at the corresponding [issue ticket](https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/2229#issuecomment-59030524)

Comment: @seven-phases-max: That is a even more cool option. Would you mind if I update the answer (ofcourse with attribution :))?

Comment: @Harry, Sure I do not mind (as always).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Less, everything is technically a `mixin` irrespective of whether we write it with parantheses (as in with parameters) or without parantheses (as in like a CSS class selector). The only difference between the two is that when the parantheses are present, the properties present within it are not output unless called from within a selector block.

> **Quoting the Less Website:**
>
> It is legal to define multiple mixins with the same name and number of parameters. Less will use properties of all that can apply.

In this case, since the other `mixin` has a default value for its only parameter, both the properties can apply when called without any parameter and hence there is no way to avoid it from happening.

**Workaround Solution:** One possible solution to work-around this problem is to enclose all such conflicting rules within a parent selector (like `body`).

```
.placeholder(@color: #333333) {
    &::-webkit-input-placeholder  { color: @color; }
}

input {
    .placeholder();
}

body{
    .placeholder{
        margin-top: 20px;
    }
}
```

**Compiled CSS:**

```
input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: #333333;
}
body .placeholder {
    margin-top: 20px;
}
```

---

**Option 2:** Extracted from the solution posted by [seven-phases-max](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2712740/seven-phases-max) in the [Less GitHub Issue thread](https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/2229#issuecomment-59030524).

> For the particular use-case one of possible workarounds is to isolate conflicting classes in unnamed scope so they won't interfere with external names:

```js
.placeholder(@color: #333333) {
    &::-webkit-input-placeholder  { color: @color; }
}

input {
    .placeholder();
}

& { // unnamed namespace
    .placeholder {
        background: #ffffff;
    }
} // ~ end of unnamed namespace
```

**Note:** The above is a straight copy/paste from the GitHub thread without any modifications so as to not tamper with the information.

Answer (score 1):

```
@mixin placeholder(@color: #333333) {
    &::-webkit-input-placeholder  { color: @color; }
}

input {
    @include placeholder();
}

.placeholder {
    margin-top: 20px;
}
```

that should work.

Comment: First issue is that this does not compile when put into [winnless](http://winless.org/online-less-compiler) second is that the first two are part of Bootstrap and something I'd try to avoid modifying

Answer (score -1):

So if i understood right, you just want to add 20px on top of the placeholder ? Add padding-top to input instead.

```
input {
    padding-top: 20px;
}
```

Comment: You understood incorrectly. The above code is just psuedo code illustrating the problem I'm having. For some reason the less compiler treats the mixin `.placeholder(@color: #333333) { ... }` and the css-selector `.placeholder { ... }` as mixins. Which renders the undesired output `input { margin-top: 20px }`